# What is returned through a jq filter on a json object in bash?

Tags: json, bash, curl

I have a JSON object that I sift through to get three strings (at most) through a curl command in bash. The command looks like this:

```
curl -s --request GET --user <USERNAME> "<DOMAIN>.com/........" --header 'Accept: application/json' | jq .one[].two.three[]
```

And it returns something like this:

```
"String 1"
"String 2"
"String 3"
```

I know that the curl command returns a JSON object, and I know the jq command filters it.

The issue is that I don't understand what that jq returns (literally, as in a one-line string, a string array, a character array, etc). What does my full command return after being filtered out with jq? Is it still a JSON object? And if so, how can I store it in an array in bash? I want to be able to sort through this and check if a string exists.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Everything is a string.  `jq` is printing the string `"String 1"\n"String 2"\n"String 3"\n`.  It is also returning a value (probably 0), and you are currently ignoring it.

Comment: It returns three JSON strings.

Comment: stdout is _always_ a stream of bytes. It can't be anything else. If you parse that stream into a character array, or into anything else... well, that's how you're interpreting it.

Comment: (If you want to make jq be guaranteed to emit one JSON document per line of output, add the `-c` argument, and _don't_ add the `-r` argument; without `-c`, some kinds of JSON output will be split across multiple lines, and that won't play well with a lot of the code you might want to write).

Comment: ...anyhow, can you try to ask a more specific question? Ideally, it should be narrow and specific enough to distinguish it from any similar questions (such as the one I closed it as a duplicate of).

Comment: `jq` reads a stream of JSON values and outputs a stream of JSON values. In between, it parses the input stream, manipulates the resulting abstract syntax tree, then serializes the result.